# Use part of class name as a css variable

Tags: javascript, css, wildcard

I'm using css to change the sizes of two divs so that their size represents some value that changes a few times per session.

Is there anyway to define a css class something like:

```
.shiftydiv(*) {
    width:\1;
}
```

where `\1` is whatever * matched? Then I can just add a class like `.shiftydiv25` via jquery whenever I need to change the size.

I don't need legacy support for browsers and I'd prefer not adding any dependencies.
If I can't do it with pure css I'll either create CSS classes dynamically or inject `style=` attributes into my code. Which would be better (less bad).

EDIT:
If there is  a nice way to do this with JS/jquery that would work well too.

EDIT 2:
So doing this with js is actually quite easy. oops

Comment: No, there's no way to do that with CSS, do you want to do it with javascript then, as you've tagged the question as such ?

Comment: You're setting the class with jQuery - why not also setting the width with it?

Comment: When you say `per session`, do you mean a backend server is keeping track via a cookie? Or you're using localstorage, or what? If it's localstorage then you have to use JavaScript, but if it's something like PHP, you can dynamically change the CSS on the fly with backend language.

Comment: Actually, you've fallen victim to the [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should just set the style with jQuery

Comment: Sounds like you need JQuery's `.css()` method

Comment: why u need this? maybe we have some other way

Comment: @DaveChen by session I mean "page use". Just meant to give an idea of frequency.

Comment: @slicedtoad So not based on the number of refreshes? Just time spent on the page? Ex. The page turns red when I've had it open for 2 minutes. In that case you can use some timing functions within CSS.

Comment: don't "inject" or modify style attributes. Use JS `.style` or jQuery `.css()`. For example: `$('.shifty').css('width','2px'). Also bear in mind that you can do a lot with media queries and using percentages instead of pixels.

Comment: Okay, thanks. For some reason I have never used `.css` or `.style` in js/jquery and my question is somewhat irrelevant now. Should I be closing the question or leaving it in case someone else happens to have a similar problem?

Comment: In JavaScript you can do `Element.className = 'yourHTMLclassAttributeHere';` on some Event, then just have your CSS set up to what you want already. Of course, that won't work if you have multiple classes. Then you can use jQuery, or write a tiny piece of code to take care of it.

Comment: Someone make a quick answer with `.css` and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead pure CSS use SASS/LESS and generate multiple classes?

You can use `for loop` and iterate over lets say 20 elements and make .shiftydiv1, shiftydiv2, ... shiftydiv20.

Comment: That a huge amount of bloat for a `CSS` file. Definitely not recommended.